# asp.net webform route querystring appending .aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Why is the routing appending .aspx value when extracting routedata.values

```
 routes.MapPageRoute("",
     "Contact/Edit/{Id}", "~/Contact.aspx", false,
      new RouteValueDictionary { { "Id", @"\d" }   });
```

Code for getting route values

```
   int routeval = Convert.ToInt32(RouteData.Values["Id"]);
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean - do you mean 'why does the route have contact.aspx instead of contact' ? Or are you actually seeing ".aspx" in the url for your pages ?

Comment: the routevalue above has the value for example 2.aspx instead of 2